# как сделать значок лупы?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать значок лупы ( просто лупа,без строчки ввода и тд ) справа от всего текста в нав.панеле,подскажите пожалуйста

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(70, 67, 68);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar>img {
  width: 19px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Iphone</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/747.png" alt="">
    <div class="nav-list">
      <a href="#">Магазин</a>
      <a href="#">Mac</a>
      <a href="#">Ipad</a>
      <a href="#">Iphone</a>
      <a href="#">Watch</a>
      <a href="#">AirPods</a>
      <a href="#">TV и Дом</a>
      <a href="#">Только в Apple</a>
      <a href="#">Аксессуары</a>
      <a href="#">Поддержка</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ну так и посмотрите на сайте эпл. Там картинка.

Comment: там значок ,а не картинка

Comment: Может у вас какой-то другой `apple.com`, но в моём это SVG-картинка https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dEZN.png

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/icons/magnifying-glass?s=solid&f=classic

Comment: а как его сделать справа от всего текста ?